# Wpf MVVM and editing DatagridCell

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

In an MVVM project the row of a Datagrid is bound is bound to an object OA and a column of the datagrid is bound to property PB=`Code.Value` of this object.

`Binding="{Binding Code.Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"`

After changing the property PB we do `OnPropertyChanged("Code");`

This seems to work all right, except that when I have edited the value PB in the cell of the datagrid and then click on another control outside the datagrid or on another row of the datagrid or also when I use the enter key, then the setter of property PB is triggered with a blank value `""`. This is triggered via "external code".

I noticed that when I edit the cell a second time, this does not happen ...

The source code of xaml datagrid:

```
<DataGrid Style="{StaticResource MyDataGrid}" BorderBrush="Black" Width="150"
        BorderThickness="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Grid.Row="2" Height="200" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ColumnHeaderHeight="24" Margin="4" 
        VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="true" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
        EnableRowVirtualization="True" EnableColumnVirtualization="True" HeadersVisibility="Column"
        SelectedItem="{Binding ItemSelection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, IsAsync=True}"
        SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" GridLinesVisibility="None" SelectionChanged="Grid_SelectionChanged" >

<DataGrid.Columns>

    <DataGridTextColumn CanUserSort="False" CanUserReorder="false" Header="Name" Width="*" 
            Binding="{Binding Code.Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" >
        <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridCellEdit}"/>
        </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource dgTextBlockViewLinks}">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Code.Tooltip}"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Code.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Code.Foreground}"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource dgTextBoxEditLeft}">
                <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="20"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>

</DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

Maybe someone has an intuition of what is going on here.
I would very much like to prevent using canceledits and/or commitedits on the cell.

Comment: what do you mean triggered via "External Code"

Comment: What I mean is, that after hitting Enter in the UI the code enters the setter of `Code.Value` with a blank value but the call stack of VS shows that it comes from External Code. When I hit enter the datagridcell shows the correct value that I entered manually via the UI, but there is a system call that updates this value to a blank value.

Comment: Maybe validation failed because datacolumn type doesn't match input type data...

Comment: either it is validation, or converter or some template that hides actual cell... share your xaml might be a little useful, also do check if source to view update works fine

Comment: I checked and there is no validation error (also second time it works) and update source to view works fine. Added xaml code.